# Insert parameters in a Devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am trying to customize a Devise registrations controller for a context where the user cannot enter an email address as their email has been manually entered previously before they can access the signup page. To achieve this in the UI, I have overridden the `new.html.erb` template to prefill the email field and to mark it in HTML as disabled:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email", disabled: true %>
```

I prefill the email in the overridden registrations controller:

```
def new
  super do |resource|
    resource.email = required_email
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, in Rails this means that the resulting POST call made when the form is submitted has no email parameter†. That is actually good, as I don't want the user to be able to modify their email in the browser by working around the disabled field or by injecting a different address a different way. The problem is that I need to also insert this email into the resulting params in the `create` action so that the user object is properly validated.

I have tried overriding the params in the controller:

```
def signup_params
  super.merge(email: required_email)
end
```

I have tried also setting the resource attributes the same was as I do in the `new` action (shown above).

None of these have any result, as I still get a validation error that "Email can't be blank". I have attempted to dive into the Devise source code to inspect how the form params are handled, but it is complicated enough a system that I cannot see any easy hooks or methods to call to modify the process.

---

† I am aware that this is intended behavior for `disabled` fields, and I am actually implementing the field as `readonly`, however I am using `disabled` here as I also want the ability to, in theory, add the parameter even if there is no field for it in the form.

Comment: You could embed the email into the HTML since you already know it. Then add a hidden field with the email. If that is not secure enough for you, you could encrypt the email address that you put in the hidden field. That way if they try to send something else in the params it will get scrambled in the un-encrypting of the hidden field value.

Comment: Round-trip for the email value is possible in theory, however it feels very much not the right solution. I have the value in the controller, I should be able to either inject it into the params or add it to the model before it gets validated/saved, but I cannot find the hooks within Devise to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to sidestep devise entirely and inject the param at the Rails level:

```
def create
  params[:user].merge!(email: required_email)

  # Other override code
end
```